# How to use ffmpeg -t when using a live YouTube source with youtube-dl?

Tags: ffmpeg, recording, youtube-dl

I wanted to download a youtube stream from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I adding the amount of time that I like. Therefore using youtube-dl, I get all its formats:

```
$ youtube-dl --list-formats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Extracting video information
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading MPD manifest
[info] Available formats for 0R0T0mQmx7I:
format code  extension  resolution note
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  144k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k
160          mp4        256x144    144p  124k , avc1.42c00b, 30fps, video only
133          mp4        426x240    240p  258k , avc1.4d4015, 30fps, video only
134          mp4        640x360    360p  646k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only
135          mp4        854x480    480p 1171k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only
136          mp4        1280x720   720p 2326k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only (best)
```

I realized that the audio and video are in different formats so it will not be straightforward. So I use the following command to extract the audio and video:

```
$ ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 136 -g  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) -i $(youtube-dl -f 140 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -t 00:02:00 output.mp4
```

But it doesn't work. It just records until 5 seconds and that's all. I tried moving "-t 00:02:00" parameter in different places and doesn't work. Anyone knows the solution? Thanks !!

**EDITED:** 
Adding the output

```
$ ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 136 -g  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) -i $(youtube-dl -f 140 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -t 00:02:00 output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://r1---sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?keepalive=yes&source=yt_live_broadcast&pl=24&itag=136&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1521354001&c=WEB&sparams=aitags%2Ccmbypass%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Chang%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clive%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnoclen%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C160&signature=727E04BDE2851159A8A9327CDBAB503BBDC37267.2168845A24D2FFD5496AA2F5D2D6AACA59BB69D2&cmbypass=yes&ipbits=0&hang=1&beids=%5B9466592%5D&ms=lv&mt=1521331971&mv=u&live=1&key=yt6&ip=152.168.37.75&id=0R0T0mQmx7I.0&gir=yes&mm=32&mn=sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6&ei=sbCtWvOcLJTWxAS644e4Ag&noclen=1&gcr=ar&requiressl=yes&ratebypass=yes':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-03-17 07:02:10
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2419 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2413 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-17 07:02:10
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://r1---sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ip=152.168.37.75&mm=32&mn=sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6&expire=1521354004&pl=24&gir=yes&signature=16F13864FDF56FFDF2E08B248355CD1257D2E4FF.C7DBD2A865733005704660CD0EA82A90EFCFC03D&id=0R0T0mQmx7I.0&mt=1521331971&mv=u&ms=lv&hang=1&ipbits=0&itag=140&gcr=ar&requiressl=yes&source=yt_live_broadcast&keepalive=yes&ei=s7CtWsq0Ko7UxQT__pSgBA&noclen=1&sparams=cmbypass%2Ccompress%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Chang%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clive%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnoclen%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&cmbypass=yes&compress=yes&key=yt6&mime=audio%2Fmp4&c=WEB&live=1&ratebypass=yes':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-03-17 07:02:09
  Duration: 00:00:04.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 130 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-17 07:02:09
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp4 @ 0x264eb20] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2413 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-17 07:02:10
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-17 07:02:09
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  150 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1557kB time=00:00:04.99 bitrate=2555.6kbits/s    
video:1473kB audio:79kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.353100%
```

Comment: Can you add the complete, uncut output from ffmpeg?

Comment: Does it work *without* `-t`?  And does your `-t` command work with downloaded files instead of URLs?

Comment: First question: without "-t" only record 5 seconds
Second one: using other urls works properly but I have never use two inputs in ffmeg
Recording only 5 seconds seems to be something weird...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**: Update `ffmpeg` ± `youtube-dl`.

Including the console output was helpful!

## Your inputs are only detected as 5 seconds long

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://r1---sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?keepalive=yes&source=yt_live_broadcast&pl=24&itag=136&mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1521354001&c=WEB&sparams=aitags%2Ccmbypass%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Chang%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clive%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnoclen%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C160&signature=727E04BDE2851159A8A9327CDBAB503BBDC37267.2168845A24D2FFD5496AA2F5D2D6AACA59BB69D2&cmbypass=yes&ipbits=0&hang=1&beids=%5B9466592%5D&ms=lv&mt=1521331971&mv=u&live=1&key=yt6&ip=152.168.37.75&id=0R0T0mQmx7I.0&gir=yes&mm=32&mn=sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6&ei=sbCtWvOcLJTWxAS644e4Ag&noclen=1&gcr=ar&requiressl=yes&ratebypass=yes':
  Metadata:
...
   Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2419 kb/s

Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://r1---sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ip=152.168.37.75&mm=32&mn=sn-j5cax8pnpvo-x1xe6&expire=1521354004&pl=24&gir=yes&signature=16F13864FDF56FFDF2E08B248355CD1257D2E4FF.C7DBD2A865733005704660CD0EA82A90EFCFC03D&id=0R0T0mQmx7I.0&mt=1521331971&mv=u&ms=lv&hang=1&ipbits=0&itag=140&gcr=ar&requiressl=yes&source=yt_live_broadcast&keepalive=yes&ei=s7CtWsq0Ko7UxQT__pSgBA&noclen=1&sparams=cmbypass%2Ccompress%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Chang%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clive%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnoclen%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&cmbypass=yes&compress=yes&key=yt6&mime=audio%2Fmp4&c=WEB&live=1&ratebypass=yes':
  Metadata:
   ...
  Duration: 00:00:04.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 130 kb/s
```

## Your `ffmpeg` version is quite old

> `ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers`

2.8 dates from around early 2016, from what I can tell. You are strongly suggested to update to the latest `ffmpeg`; preferably the latest `git HEAD`, but otherwise [this PPA might be of use](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-3) for Ubuntu.

## Update your `youtube-dl` version as well

I get quite a different output from you for the same URL:

```
$ youtube-dl --list-formats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Extracting video information
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading m3u8 information
[youtube] 0R0T0mQmx7I: Downloading MPD manifest
[info] Available formats for 0R0T0mQmx7I:
format code  extension  resolution note
91           mp4        256x144    HLS  197k , avc1.42c00b, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.5@ 48k
92           mp4        426x240    HLS  338k , avc1.4d4015, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.5@ 48k
93           mp4        640x360    HLS  829k , avc1.4d401e, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2@128k
94           mp4        854x480    HLS 1380k , avc1.4d401f, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2@128k
95           mp4        1280x720   HLS 2593k , avc1.4d401f, 30.0fps, mp4a.40.2@256k (best)
$ youtube-dl --version
2018.03.14
```

## With a recent `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` version, you get the expected result:

```
$ ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 91 -g  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) \
-i $(youtube-dl -f 95 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) \
-c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -t 00:02:00 output.mp4

(...)

$ ffprobe output.mp4
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:02:00.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1784 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv,     bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1648kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Example (video) output, resized to fit 2MB upload limit:

[image]

[Full output from `ffmpeg` invocation](http://ix.io/YVd).

Comment: Thanks !! It's working but watching the output video I realized that It freezes several times. Do you know if could be something about a missing parameter? I'm using cmd: `$ ffmpeg -i $(youtube-dl -f 95 -g  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0R0T0mQmx7I) -t 00:02:00 output.ts`

Comment: The error seems to be about `skipping 5 segments ahead, expired from playlists` that it is in the output. I don't know how to deal with them...

Comment: Any help with skipping segments??

Comment: @gat00n I don't see those messages in the output I have here; I'll need to watch the 2 min sample I produced to see if there are any skips. That sounds like it might be worthy of a [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) (perhaps linking back to this one for reference) as it seems to be a different issue :)

Comment: That's for sure. I've upvoted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @gat00n Thanks :) I'll keep an eye out for the related question!